# Wordpress Website deploying challenge, remove "Allow from all" .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I am attempting to host my website. My host'er is telling me that they dont support "Allow from all" in .htaccess.

Below are the contents of wp-content/.htaccess

```
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
<files  ?\.(jpg|gif|png|js|css)$? ~>
    Allow from all
</files>
```

What impact negative/positive will I have by removing, just the  part lines on my setup ?

Comment: Do you need that configuration for anything?

Comment: You might get a better response on the [WordPress site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: My question got downvoted at wordpress. I was advised to open a question here. I request that I dont get ping ponged between serverfault and wordpress. My question is answered and I am happy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `Allow from all` is self contained to only those files you inherently gain/lose nothing. That is one of those things that shouldn't be there as it is literally serving no purpose. You do not have a directive in `<Files` that is `deny`ing, so it's pointless to have it.

The technical reason why that it's pointless is because: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html

And if I'm wrong it's because of the opposite: it's harder to read, especially in vhost files. If you need to setup ACL you should explicitly define them per `<Files` rather than attempting to "inherit" previous ACL's.

Also, because it's in .htaccess everything is being denied access to. So, even though you have allow all, the deny rule is applied last. I'd bet that in this case none of your content is visible?

Comment: Super, I'll remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I removed all the lines from .htaccess and then it worked. Just removing 'files' wouldn't help.

```
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
<files  ?\.(jpg|gif|png|js|css)$? ~>
    Allow from all
</files>
```

Thanks to @user973917